# After add new node view without reload page in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs3, ext-designer

when i create sub node using fallowing function newly create node not view in the tree nodes. but reload page using press F5 key. show newly create node in the tree nodes
how can i view node without reload webpage?

```
  createSubCategory: function() {
     dt    = new Date();
     id    = dt.format('U');
     name  = 'New Sub-Category'
     if(this.treepanelSkillCat.selModel.selNode == null) 
     {
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
           buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
           icon:Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
        });
        return false;   
     }         
     var parent        = this.treepanelSkillCat.selModel.selNode.id;      

     var newNode       = new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({id: id, text: name, leaf: false});
     form_data         = {'SKL_CAT_ID': id , 'SKL_CAT_NAME' : name, 'PARENT_SKL_CAT_ID' :parent }; 

     this.nodeAction   = 'addtotree';
     this.selNode      = newNode;   

     this.submitNode(form_data,'addtotree');
     this.treepanelSkillCat.selModel.selNode.appendChild(newNode);
  },
```

[image: before reload][image: after reload can view newly add sub child node in the last node as below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reloading the treePanel store in the callback of your submitNode method.